# TodayArchiveview is not detected in urls.py(Django)

Tags: python, django

I created several date-based views in Django, and while views for year and month function as expected, the view to display today is not detected. For instance, if I try to get http://127.0.0.1:8000/blog/archive/2021/jan or http://127.0.0.1:8000/blog/archive/2021/jan/07/ the views will be displayed, http://127.0.0.1:8000/blog/archive/today/ will fail. I understand that the problem must be with urls.py configuration, but I just cannot find it in documentation.

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path, re_path

from blog import views

app_name = 'blog'

urlpatterns = [
    # Example: /blog/
    path('', views.PostListView.as_view(), name='index'),

    # Example: /blog/post/ (same as /blog/)
    path('post/', views.PostListView.as_view(), name='post_list'),

    # Example: /blog/post/django-example/
    re_path(r'^post/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', views.PostDetailView.as_view(), name='post_detail'),

    # Example: /blog/archive/
    path('archive/', views.PostArchiveView.as_view(), name='post_archive'),

    # Example: /blog/archive/2019/
    path('archive/<int:year>/', views.PostYearArchiveView.as_view(), name='post_year_archive'),

    # Example: /blog/archive/2019/nov/
    path('archive/<int:year>/<str:month>/', views.PostMonthArchiveView.as_view(month_format = '%b'), name='post_month_archive'),

    # Example: /blog/archive/2019/nov/10/
    path('archive/<int:year>/<str:month>/<int:day>/', views.PostDayArchiveView.as_view(), name='post_day_archive'),

    # Example: /blog/archive/today/
    path('archive/today/', views.PostTodayArchiveView.as_view(), name='post_today_archive'),
]
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView, ArchiveIndexView, YearArchiveView, MonthArchiveView, \
    DayArchiveView, TodayArchiveView

from blog.models import Post


class PostListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'blog/post_all.html'
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    paginate_by = 2


class PostDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Post


class PostArchiveView(ArchiveIndexView):
    model = Post
    date_field = 'modify_dt'


class PostYearArchiveView(YearArchiveView):
    model = Post
    date_field = 'modify_dt'
    make_object_list = True


class PostMonthArchiveView(MonthArchiveView):
    model = Post
    date_field = 'modify_dt'


class PostDayArchiveView(DayArchiveView):
    model = Post
    date_field = 'modify_dt'
    day_format = '%d'


class PostTodayArchiveView(TodayArchiveView):
    model = Post
    date_field = 'modify_dt'
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
from django.urls import reverse


class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(verbose_name='TITLE', max_length=50)
    slug = models.SlugField('SLUG', unique=True, allow_unicode=True, help_text='one word for title alias.')
    description = models.CharField('DESCRIPTION', max_length=100, blank=True, help_text='simple description text.')
    content = models.TextField('CONTENT')
    create_dt = models.DateTimeField('CREATE DATE', auto_now_add=True)
    modify_dt = models.DateTimeField('MODIFY DATE', auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'post'
        verbose_name_plural = 'posts'
        db_table = 'blog_posts'
        ordering = ('-modify_dt',)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('blog:post_detail', args=(self.slug,))

    def get_previous(self):
        return self.get_previous_by_modify_dt()

    def get_next(self):
        return self.get_next_by_modify_dt()
```

**errors**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/class-based-views/generic-date-based/#todayarchiveview

Your class PostTodayArchiveView should look like this

```
class PostTodayArchiveView(TodayArchiveView):
    queryset = Post.objects.all()
    date_field = "modify_dt"
    allow_future = True
```